# Why is my jQuery not live?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery script. When I check the `snow[enabled]` checkbox, it does not show the `#overlay` div, live. It only checks on page load...

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        $('.color-field').wpColorPicker();
        $('#TB_window').draggable();
    });
    $(function() {
        if ($("#image-url").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0) {
            $("#has-image").show();
        }
        if(document.getElementById('snow[enabled]').checked) {
            $("#overlay").show();
        } else {
            $("#overlay").hide();
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

How can I make this live? So, even after page load check if `snow[enabled]` is checked, if so show the div?

Comment: This script runs when the page loads and that's it.  It doesn't *keep* running/looping.  You'd need to add an `onchange` event to the checkbox and toggle `#overlay` in the event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind onchange event to the checkbox.

Then you can simply toggle the overlay.

```
$('input#snow').on('change', function () {
    $("#overlay").toggle();
});
```

OR

You can use if else condition depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not, to get more reliable result.

```
$('input#snow').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $("#overlay").show();
    } else {
        $("#overlay").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example for the `:checked` selector in jQuery API, which shows how to bind a function on the `click` event of a checkbox to see whether it was checked or unchecked.

https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
<script>
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  $( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
countChecked();

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>
```